# Añadir datos a una matriz bidimensional

Tags: java, array, matrices

Este es mi código pero no me imprime la matriz correctamente me tiene que añadir un numero por cada posición de la matriz por ejemplo: matriz de 3x3

```
[1/9][2/9][3/9]
[4/9][5/9][5/9]
[7/9][8/9][9/9]
```

**la matriz debe mostrarla en decimales**

imprimir el numero de la posición dividido en m que es igual al la dimensión de la matriz en este caso 3*3 = 9 = m

```
     short n3 = 0;
    short n4 = 0;
    System.out.println("Introduce el numero de filas");
    n3 +=Short.parseShort(sc.nextLine());
    
    System.out.println("Introduce el numero de columnas");
    n4 += Short.parseShort(sc.nextLine());

    float m = n3*n4;

    float [][] matriz2 = new float[n3][n4];

    for (int i = 0; i < matriz2.length; i++) {
        
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz2[i].length; j++) {
            matriz2 [i][j] = i++/m;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Funciones.imprimeArrayF(matriz2));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

un dato como este `[1/9]` no puede ser guardado en un matriz de tipo numérico,lo mas recomendable es que lo guardes en una matriz de tipo `String` en la cual puedes agregar caracteres como `"/"`

```
n4 += Short.parseShort(sc.nextLine());
```

al colocar += es lo mismo que poner

```
n4 =n4+Short.parseShort(sc.nextLine());
```

innecesario si buscas guardar el valor de Sscanner

```
float m = n3*n4;
```

Al hacer eso te devolverá un numero decimal 9.0,4.0 etc pero tu matriz debe ser un entero "/" entero...siendo así tendrías lo siguiente

```
System.out.println("Introduce el numero de filas");
n3 =Short.parseShort(sc.nextLine());

System.out.println("Introduce el numero de columnas");
n4 = Short.parseShort(sc.nextLine());

int m = n3*n4;

String [][] matriz2 = new String[n3][n4];
int k=1;
for (int i = 0; i < matriz2.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matriz2[i].length; j++) {
        matriz2 [i][j] ="["+k+"/"+m+"] ";
        k++;
    }
}
```